# As Lie group, the isometry group of Riemannian manifold and its subgroup.

Tags: riemannian-geometry, lie-groups

[Myers-Steenrod theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Myers-Steenrod+theorem) says that the isometry group $\text{Iso}(M)$ of a Riemannian manifold $M$ is a Lie group. I am interested in the subgroup
$$\text{Iso}_+(M)=\lbrace g\in \text{Iso}(M):\text{$g$ preserves the orientation of $M$} \rbrace$$
for an oriented Riemannian manifold $M$. Is it a (closed) Lie subgroup of $\text{Iso}(M)$? And I ask you in what conditions for $M$ the subgroup is compact.

Comment: The Lie group topology of $Iso(M)$ agrees with the topology of uniform convergence on compacta. If $M$ is oriented then the isometries preserving the orientation are a closed and open subgroup, and so a union of connected components. Its a finite index subgroup, and so its compact if and only if $Iso(M)$ is. If $M$ is compact you can for example conclude that $Iso(M)$ is compact.